# Using BibTeX, how do I create a custom in-text author name which is a shortened version of the reference author name (not just 'et. al')?

Tags: natbib

I am citing a U.N. report which does not list a set of author names. I am using bibliography-style `AuthorDate1` and the package `natbib`. The report's details are set down in my .bib file under the category `@techreport` (because this seems the most appropriate one, with useful fields (but of course I am not tied to it)). In the `author` field, I have placed `United Nations, Department of Economic and Social Affairs, Population Division`. However, I do not want this unwieldy phrase to appear in my in-text citations. By default, the packages in play do not cause this whole phrase to appear in the in-text citation, but (unsurprisingly) they do not shorten it in the way I would desire, namely, `U.N. Population Division`.

I know that I have options here. I could, for example, write down the author as `U.N. Population Division` and put the rest of the information in some other field, like `Institution` in my .bib file. However, I think that would make the reference look weird and so is suboptimal. Surely, there must be a way to set-up some kind of alternative author shorthand... right?

Comment: Please post the entire entry in question as part of your query. Should citation call-outs to this entry mention the year of publication as well, or just the shortened name of the (corporate) author? Incidentally, the reason why BibTeX shortens the "full" author field at present is that you've failed to encase the author field in an extra pair of curly braces. What you need is `author = {{United Nations, Department of Economic and Social Affairs, Population Division}}`.

Comment: `biblatex` has the field `shortauthor` for that, but it seems that `AuthorDate1.bst` doesn't have a similar thing. You could hack the `.bst` file and add support for a `shortauthor`, but that would be a bit of work and not really portable. A simple (but not particularly pretty) workaround would involve `\defcitealias{unrep}{U. N. Population Divison 2009}`, but that can either imitate `\cite`/`\citep` or `\citet`, but not both.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have decided to use a hacky work-around

Comment: @NoamHudson - No need for any hacks. Do read the `natbib` user guide and, in particular, the section on citation aliases.

Comment: ok! ------------